# IF/OR Function Excel 2010

Tags: if-statement, excel-2010

I have been searching for an answer and can't seem to find one. I have multiple OR conditions within an IF statement.

**What I need is:**

If L3 OR M3 OR N3 or O3 OR P3 OR Q3 >0 then X3=Past

If R3 >0 then X3=Present

If S3 OR T3 or U3 or V3 > 0 then X3=Future

**The problem is the following are also true:**

If L3 OR M3 OR N3 or O3 OR P3 OR Q3 OR R3 > 0 then X3=Past, Present

If L3 OR M3 OR N3 or O3 OR P3 OR Q3 OR S3 OR T3 or U3 or V3 >0 then X3=Past, Future

If L3 OR M3 OR N3 or O3 OR P3 OR Q3 OR R3 OR S3 OR T3 or U3 or V3 >0 then X3=Past, Present, Future

This is my non-working code thus far:

```
=(IF(OR($L3>0, $M3>0, $N3>0, $O3>0, $P3>0, $Q3>0),"Past"),      IF(OR($R3=0),”Present”),IF(OR($S105>0,$T105>0,$U105>0,$V105>0),"Future" ,NoDate)))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct answer is

```
=IF(OR($L3>0,$M3>0,$N3>0,$O3>0,$P3>0,$Q3>0),"Past",IF(OR($R3=0),"Present",IF(OR($S105>0,$T105>0,$U105>0,$V105>0),"Future","NoDate")))
```

Check your parentesis, quote "NoDate".
The trick is

```
=IF(conditions,"Past",IF(conditions,"Present",IF(conditions,"Future","NoDate")))
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!